# Calculating Probabilities (Problem)

Tags: probability

So I have this problem:

- First box has 5 white and 4 black balls
- Second box has 6 white and 3 black balls
- Third box has one random ball from each box

What is the chance to have 2 white balls in the third box? ( my answer is approximately 37% but I am quite unsure )

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Case 1-

From first box white ball is picked. We have,

$\frac{5}{5+4} = \frac 59$

Case 2-

From second box white ball is picked. We have,

$\frac{6}{6+3} = \frac 69$

Probability of both whites in third box

$ = \frac 59 ×  \frac 69 =  \frac {30}{81}$ = 0.37 or 37%

Comment: I have additional question. Let's say we take out one ball and it is white. Then we calculate again the chance for the second to be white? Is it different?

Comment: If without replacement then its different. If with replacement then same.

Comment: What is it like without replacement?

Comment: Suppose you have 4 white and 5 red. Then probability of one ball drawn without replacement to be white is $\frac49$. Without replacement so you left with 3 white and 5 red. One another ball is picked. Then probability of white is $\frac38$. Not same.

Comment: Suppose you have 4 white and 5 red. Then probability of one ball drawn with replacement to be white is $\frac49$. With replacement so you have again 4 white and 5 red. One another ball is picked. Then probability of white is $\frac49$. Same.

Comment: In the current problem drawing first white ball would be 11/18 and second 10/17 (no replacement). Correct?

Comment: Yes if you have 11 white and 7 black balls. And I have written red instead of black in my above comments.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{5}{5+4}$ is the probability to draw a white ball from the first box

$\frac{6}{6+3}$ is the probability to draw a white ball from the seond box

So the probability to have two white in the third box is 
$\frac{5}{5+4}\frac{6}{6+3} = \frac{30}{81} \approx 0.37$